# De-compile .application program in c# // undo code already saved before in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, decompiler

I made a program and did a `.application` file. Then I kept doing changes to the code in Visual Studio and now I want to go back to the same code that I had but the only thing close to that code is that `.application` program.

Comment: 1. Use version control so you do not find yourself in this situation. 2. JetBrains dotPeek is a free software that will decompile .NET assemblies, https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/

Comment: Definitely start using version control in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Use version control so you do not find yourself in this situation in the future

Since you are in this situation, JetBrains dotPeek is a free software that will decompile .NET assemblies,

http://jetbrains.com/decompiler

Answer (score 0):

An `.application` file is a text (xml) file.  It loads the `.exe` file from an external location into something of a cache.

I use task manager -> process -> properties to identify the physical `.exe` location and use my preferred decompiler on that.